# Anaconda navigator won't install the OpenCV library in the environments

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I'am trying to install the OpenCv and OpenBlas libraries in the Anaconda Navigator environments section.
[image]

When I click on the apply button it should download the two libraries but instead this window is opened: 
[image]
I already waited for an hour but nothing has changed. In a tutorial it said it would only take about 3 minutes. 
On the internet some people said the problem could be fixed by updating anaconda to a newer version so i Tried these two commands in the mac terminal:

```
conda upgrade conda
```

and

```
conda upgrade anaconda-navigator
```

But after this nothing changed. I even tried restarting the computer but the same window opened again when trying to install the libraries.

Does anyone know a different solution to this problem?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: There is currently a speed issue as conda repositories grew really large over past years. You can find some explanations and recommendations in the [anaconda blog](https://www.anaconda.com/understanding-and-improving-condas-performance/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seemed to solve the problem for me is first entering this command:

```
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

in the mac terminal. Then when trying to install the libraries again the window opened again but changed into the option to download the libraries after a while.